# Creating chart into excel using mvc3 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create a chart using C#. 
It works fine when I create a view of it. 
But can someone tell me how to put this chart into an excel file? 
I'm using nHibernate and ninject for my MVC3 application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past I've used the OpenXML SDK from MS.  I'd start there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180830.aspx#odc_Office14_ta_GenerateExcelWorkbookswithOpenXMLSDK20_Introduction